# What is the string limit with the Arduino ide?

Tags: c, arduino

I'm trying to print multiple quotes in a `Keyboard.print()` function but when i try to escape the character with \ at  `$output =\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\""` and the string does not get recognized by the ide. Usually when the ide knows it's a string it highlights the text in blue, it does not do that for $output and after $output how can I make the ide recognize every escaped character as a string it's only recognizing half.

```
Keyboard.print("\"cd $HOME\""; $folder=mkdir \"Misc\""; $folder; $url=\"https://test.org/cc.zip\""; $output =\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\""; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=NewObject -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\") foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\Misc\").CopyHere($item)}");
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is that really supposed to be C? Even without knowing what it is, looks like a missing `)` near the start. Or is it one to many `"` after HOME? Without knowing what you are trying to print, it is hard to tell!

Comment: not what's in the string but the Keyboard.print() yes

Comment: sorry I edited the code it does have a closing ) at the end. I'm trying to print a powershell line but I don't think that matters, because I want to print it as a string and I also want the  double quotes to be included when I print that line, I have been reading and some recommend to use  \" \"" to print quotes but it's not working   @John3136

Comment: [Don't cross post.](https://arduino.stackexchange.com/questions/32339/printing-multiple-double-qoutes-in-print-statement)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two double quotes`"` after `HOME`. The first one is escaped (and so printed), but the second one ends the string so the `; $folder=mkdir` is not part of the string you are printing - it is expected to be valid C.

The IDE is trying to figure that out, but is not valid C and so it gets confused.

This is a good example of the IDE actually helping you. The IDE has noticed a problem and highlighted it for you!

Comment: okay now it's like this   `Keyboard.print(\"cd $HOME\"; $folder=mkdir \"Misc\"; $folder;$url=\"foobar/test-.zip\""; ` $output =\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\"; (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile($url,$output); $shell=NewObject -ComObject shell.application; $zip=$shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\Misc\nc.zip\") foreach ($item in $zip.items()) { $shell.NameSpace(\"$HOME\Misc\").CopyHere($item)});
and still only thinks that the string is only up to $output

Comment: because you have the same problem (2 quotes) after "test-.zip"

Comment: if i take the quote off the string is not recognized as a string I added two images above so you can see difference, when blue it knows it's a string when not blue it's not a string.

Comment: Perhaps strip it down to something readable? From the images it looks like you don't have an "non escaped" `"` at the start...